How to correctly sign out from an MSAL desktop app that uses WAM, RemoveAsyc isn't removing the account
I have a WPF desktop app, .NET 8, that uses MSAL and the WAM broker to get a token.
I configure WAM as such:
            BrokerOptions brokerOptions = new BrokerOptions(BrokerOptions.OperatingSystems.Windows);
            brokerOptions.ListOperatingSystemAccounts = true;
            builder.WithBroker(brokerOptions);

I am using the code below that you find on the Microsoft website and many other locations (GitHub) to sign-out of all the accounts when I'm done with the token.
When I use this code, it enters an endless loop at (accounts.Any()) because the call to RemoveAsync() does not appear to remove the accounts. The code compiles correctly and there are no exceptions. What could cause this?
        var accounts = await App.PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
        while (accounts.Any())
        {
            try
            {
                await App.PublicClientApp.RemoveAsync(accounts.First());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the exception or handle it as needed
                Console.WriteLine($"Error removing account: {ex.Message}");
            }
            accounts = await App.PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
        }


I tried the WPF desktop app with .NET 8 using MSAL and the WAM broker for Sign in to get access token and Sign out.
Code :
MainWindow.xaml :
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="SignInButton" Content="Sign In" Width="100" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="SignInButton_Click"/>
        <Button Name="SignOutButton" Content="Sign Out" Width="100" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="SignOutButton_Click"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="MessageTextBlock" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

MainWindow.xaml.cs :
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private async void SignInButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var scopes = new[] { "user.read" };
            try
            {
                var result = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                                                        .WithParentActivityOrWindow(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle)
                                                        .ExecuteAsync();
                MessageBox.Show($"Access Token: {result.AccessToken}");
            }
            catch (MsalException msalEx)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error: {msalEx.Message}");
            }
        }
        private async void SignOutButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await App.SignOutAsync();
            MessageTextBlock.Text = "Sign out successful.";
        }
    }
}

App.xaml.cs :
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client.Broker;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApp;

        public App()
        {
            var pcaOptions = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
            {
                ClientId = "{<client_id>",
                RedirectUri = "ms-appx-web://microsoft.aad.brokerplugin/<client_id>"
            };
            var builder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions);
            var brokerOptions = new BrokerOptions(BrokerOptions.OperatingSystems.Windows)
            {
                ListOperatingSystemAccounts = true
            };
            builder.WithBroker(brokerOptions);
            PublicClientApp = builder.Build();
        }
        public static async Task SignOutAsync()
        {
            var accounts = await PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
            foreach (var account in accounts)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Attempting to remove account: {account.Username}");
                    await PublicClientApp.RemoveAsync(account);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Successfully removed account: {account.Username}");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error removing account {account.Username}: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }
            accounts = await PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
            if (!accounts.Any())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("All accounts removed successfully.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Some accounts could not be removed.");
            }
        }
    }
}

App.xaml :
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

I added the following URL in the Azure AD app's Authentication URI as a Mobile and desktop applications:
ms-appx-web://microsoft.aad.brokerplugin/<client_id>


I enabled the Allow public client flows for mobile and desktop flows to Yes.

Output :
The code above ran successfully. I received the output below, clicked the Sign in button, and selected my account for signing in:

I obtained the access token as shown below:

Finally, I clicked the Sign Out button and received the Sign out successful message as shown below.


Fantastic. I am working on this now. I will get back to you shortly. I pretty much had precisely what you had EXCEPT for the "Allow public client flows". I'll cross my fingers.

OK, I tried it out and it runs. Authenticates correctly. Displays the token. When I go to sign out it displays the email addresses of 3 accounts and says "Successfully removed account:" for each. It then displays Sign out successful in the main window. However, in the output, it also displays "Some accounts could not be removed". When I stop the app in the debugger at the second "accounts = await PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync()", I see that the same number of accounts present that were there before the block that executed the PublicClientApp.RemoveAsync(); So, are accounts really removed?

@Intensivist Yes, those accounts removed.
